# In Firestore I can not create rule to avoid overwrite

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to avoid overwriting, what's the best way to make the rules?

This rule does not work

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /audio/{title} {
      allow read;
      allow write: if request.resource.data.id != resource.data.id;
    }
  }
}
```

I tried this rule and it did not work `request.resource.id != resource.id;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [Security Rules reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/security/) documentation. Specifically the section about the `allow` statement.

> There are three operations for writes in Cloud Firestore: `create`,
>   `update`, and `delete`. These correspond to the `set()`, `add()`, `update()`,
>   `remove()`, and `transaction()` methods in the client libraries. For your
>   convenience the write operation allows all of these.
>
> ```
> // Writes are divided into create, update, and delete operations
> allow create, update, delete: if <condition>;
>
> // This is equivalent to using the write operation
> allow write: if <condition>;
> ```

Here you'll see that `allow write` is a convenience shortcut for all 3 types of mutations. For your use case you'll want something like:

```
allow create: if <condition>;
allow update, delete: if false;
```